# Soil moisture sensor compatibility

Tags: arduino, sensor, analog-to-digital

Can [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Soil-Moisture-Meter-Soil-Humidity-Sensor-Water-Sensor-Soil-Hygrometer-Ardunio-/141548503909?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item20f4f2c365&_uhb=1) sensor for ardunino can be used with raspberry pi b+ model?

> The specs of the sensor are
>
> - Operating voltage: 3.3V~5V
> - Dual output mode,analog output more accurate
> - A fixed bolt hole for easy installation
> - Having LM393 comparator chip, stable
> - VCC: 3.3V-5V
> - GND: GND

And I should use ADC along with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you give is to the soil sensor which is not an Arduino.

Did you mean to ask whether you could use the soil sensor with the Pi?

Yes you can but to get analogue results you'd need to add an ADC (I2C or SPI based ADCs are commonly available and will work with the Pi.)

If you did mean to link to an Arduino then yes you can use an Arduino with the Pi.  If the Arduino is 5V based you'd have to ensure that any Pi inputs from the Arduino were level shifted.  If the Arduino is 3V3 based there is no need.  An Arduino has in-built analogue ports so there is no need to use an ADC with an Arduino (unless you need higher accuracy than the typically 10-bit Arduino precision.

Comment: i was suppose to write it as soil sensor for ardunino.

Comment: @DushyanthShenoy In that case you will need an ADC to make full use of that sensor with the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it witout additional IC but only in 'digital' model. That means that you have to set sensitivity on device and detect high or low state on connected GPIO.
Plus, if you power this sensor from 5V you have to lower the voltage. For example with simple voltage divider. 
besides that is should work just fine